# Pandas Conditional filter on same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the pandas I use `df[df['Column']!='value']` to get desired column values.
But how can I use it for multiple condition?

I used this

```
import numpy as np
df[df['Column']!=np.nan and df['Column']!='value_x' and df['Column']!='value_y']
```

But it is throwing

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For compare missing values need [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and because priority operators add `()` in next conditions, for bitwise `AND` use `&`:

```
df[df['Column'].notna() & (df['Column']!='value_x') & (df['Column']!='value_y')]
```

Another out of box solution is replace missing values, test if `value_x` or `value_y` and invert condition by `~`:

```
df[~df['Column'].fillna('value_x').isin(['value_x','value_y'])]
```